# What can you say about the limit of $( x_n)$ as $n$ approaches infinity?

Tags: real-analysis

I have a metric space $M$ and a convergent sequence $(x_n)$ in $M$. I also have $a$ in $M$ such that:

1) the set $\{a, x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n,\dotsc\}$ is closed.

2) the set $\{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n, \dots\}$ is neither open nor closed.

What would this say about $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$? 
This is puzzling me.
Would this limit exist? Any hints would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's forget, for the moment, the information that the sequence is convergent.

The closure of a set is the union of the set with the set of its limit points. Since $X=\{x_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is not closed, but $X\cup\{a\}$ is, we conclude that $a$ is a limit point of $X$. Thus there is a sequence in $X$ that converges to $a$ and this can be taken as a subsequence of $(x_n)$ in the following way:

Set $n_1=1$; for $k>1$, define 
$$
n_k=\min\{n:d(x_n,a)<1/k, n>n_{k-1}\}
$$

Note that $X\cap B_{1/k}(a)$ is infinite for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$, because $a$ is a limit point, so the set we take the minimum of is not empty.

Then it's trivial to verify that the subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ converges to $a$.

Can we say the whole sequence converges to $a$? No. Define
$$
x_n=\begin{cases}
1/n & \text{if $n$ is even,}\\
n   & \text{if $n$ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$
Then $(x_n)$ satisfies your hypothesis with $a=0$, but it doesn't converge to $0$.

However, if we add the hypothesis that the whole sequence is convergent, then it converges to the same limit as any of its subsequences. So surely
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=a
$$
because a subsequence converges to $a$.

Comment: But part of hypothesis is the whole sequence converges.

Comment: @ChefCurryWithTheShotBoy OK, I'll fix it.

Comment: Ok, but then since the whole sequence converges we should get a limit of xn i believe.

Comment: @ChefCurryWithTheShotBoy Yes, of course, see edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that a subsequence of $\{x_i\}$ has limit $a$.

Comment: Why so? I am not seeing this?

Comment: There is a limit point of the second set that is not in the second set, because it is not closed.  It is also a limit point of the first set, but it must be in the first set because the first set is closed.  So $a$ is a limit point of $\{x_i\}$.  It may also be the limit of the sequence $\{x_i\}$, but need not be.

Comment: How would this help us make a claim about the limit of xn? It makes sense that the limit of xn is not a. Is there any crossover between the subsequence xi's limit being a and the limit of xn?

Answer (score 0):

Since the second set is not closed it does not contain all of its limit points. Therefore, there exists a sequence (say $y_n)$ in the set 2 that converges to a limit (say $b\in M$ and $b\neq x_j$). But this sequence is also in the first set. As the first set is closed, $b\in$ set $1$ but $b\neq x_j$, so b must be a! That is there exists a sequence of $x_j 's$ such that converges to $a$.

Comment: So you're saying that the limit of xn = b = a

Comment: a subsequence of $x_j's$ tends to $b=a$.

Comment: when we pick the sequence $y_n$ is the set 2, it means that $y_n$ is a subsequence of $x_n$ not necessarily $x_n$ itself.

Comment: But if yn is contained in xn isin't there a theorem that says they will converge to the same point, b? So, then the limit of the subsequence is equal to the limit of the sequence. So the limit of xn = b?

Comment: No, the limit of $x_n$ is not necessarily b.

Comment: Thanks! So is it possible to draw a specific conclusion about the limit of xn?